# responsive-loader with nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I want to integrate [responsive-loader](https://github.com/herrstucki/responsive-loader)  into my Nuxt.js project which runs in SPA mode. (Optional I want to add Vuetify Progressive Image support also).
It will be a static hosting with Netlify.

Versions:

- "nuxt": "^2.3.4"
- "responsive-loader": "^1.2.0"
- "sharp": "^0.21.1"

I found some solutions how to do it (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51982357/8804871) but this is not working for me.
When I run **npm run build**
I get an error message: **"TypeError: Cannot set property 'exclude' of undefined"**

My build section looks the following:

```
build: {
    transpile: [/^vuetify/],
    plugins: [
  new VuetifyLoaderPlugin()
],

extractCSS: true,
/*
 ** Run ESLint on save
 */
extend(config, { isDev, isClient, isServer }) {
  // Default block
  if (isDev && isClient) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      enforce: 'pre',
      test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
      loader: 'eslint-loader',
      exclude: /(node_modules)/
    })
  }

  if (isServer) {
    config.externals = [
      nodeExternals({
        whitelist: [/^vuetify/]
      })
    ]
  }
  // Default block end

  // here I tell webpack not to include jpgs and pngs
  // as base64 as an inline image
  config.module.rules.find(
    rule => rule.loader === "url-loader"
  ).exclude = /\.(jpe?g|png)$/;
  /*
  ** Configure responsive-loader
  */
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png)$/i,
    loader: "responsive-loader",
    options: {
      min: 350,
      max: 2800,
      steps: 7,
      placeholder: false,
      quality: 60,
      adapter: require("responsive-loader/sharp")
    }
  });
}
}
```

The error is probably found in this section:

```
config.module.rules.find(
    rule => rule.loader === "url-loader"
).exclude = /\.(jpe?g|png)$/;
```

Like said I get this error message: **"TypeError: Cannot set property 'exclude' of undefined"**.

I run this project along with vuetify. I also would like to enable the Progressive image support together with responsive loader. Does anybody know how to setup both rules together?
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader#progressive-images

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to integrate responsive-loader into a Nuxt.js project is to use this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-responsive-loader

Disclaimer: I created the module

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your config that it relies on `rule.loader` property but rule can be defined in `use` or `oneOf` config sections as well.
Another one problem is that nuxt internal config has several rules with `url-loader`(for images, videos, fonts ...).

In your case the rule, you tried to find, has `use` section and `url-loader` is defined there, that's why your `find` function found nothing and threw this error:

```
{
    "test": /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp)$/,
    "use": [{
        "loader": "url-loader",
        "options": {
            "limit": 1000,
            "name": "img/[hash:7].[ext]"
        }
    }]
}
```

About responsive-loader, you should remove extensions you want to process with `responsive-loader` from `url-loader` rule to avoid unexpected behavior and conflicts, here is `extend` function working example:

```
extend(config, ctx) {
  let imgTest = '/\\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp)$/';
  // find by reg ex string to not rely on rule structure
  let urlRule = config.module.rules.find(r => r.test.toString() === imgTest);

  // you can use also "oneOf" section and define both loaders there.
  // removed images from url-loader test
  urlRule.test = /\.(svg|webp)$/;

  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
    loader: "responsive-loader",
    options: {
      // place generated images to the same place as url-loader
      name: "img/[hash:7]-[width].[ext]",
      min: 350,
      max: 2800,
      steps: 7,
      placeholder: false,
      quality: 60,
      adapter: require("responsive-loader/sharp")
    }
  })
}
```

Yes, it looks dirty, but I think it's only way for now to change some loader.

What about vuetify - I think both loaders will conflict with each other and probably the solution is to use single loader that will work with your images.

Hope it helps.

### Update for Nuxt >= 2.4.0:

They modified the rules array please update the following line:

```
let imgTest = '/\\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp)$/i';
```

Then the code should work normally again.